# how to get value of all checkbox in table using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table , I want to get value of some `checkbox` and push in string. Then I'm trying a function to get value , but it shows object Object, It`s not working.

```html
  <table id="div_table" border="2px" >
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td><input  type="checkbox" value="ABC" /></td>
                <td>
<input  type="checkbox" value="123" />
<input  type="checkbox" value="456" />
<input  type="checkbox" value="789" />
</td>
                <td><input  type="checkbox" value="xyz2" />
  <input  type="checkbox" value="xyz1" />
</td>
                </tr>
 </tbody>
        </table>
```

I tried code java function

```js
  function getvalue_func()
            {
                $('#div_table > tbody  > tr').each(function() 
                {
                    var str = '';
                    $(this).find('td').find("input:checked").each(function ()
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < $(this).length; i++)
                        {
                            str += $(this).val() + ',';
                        }
                        return alert(str);
                    });         
                });
            }
```

Example : I check some checkbox: ABC,123,456 and xyz2 . Result : ABC,123,456,xyz2

Answer (score 6):

I think you want the function to return the string then

```js
function getvalue_func() {
  return $('#div_table input:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get().join(', ');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="div_table" border="2px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" value="ABC" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" value="123" />
        <input type="checkbox" value="456" />
        <input type="checkbox" value="789" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" value="xyz2" />
        <input type="checkbox" value="xyz1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="alert(getvalue_func())">get</button>
```

- you can use a simple selector `#div_table input:checked` to get all the checked checkboxes inside the `#div_table` element
- Use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to create an array of those checked checkboxes, then use [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to convert the array to a string

Comment: how do you get that Run Code Snippet button? **after** actually looking figured that one out

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say something very similar:

```
var result = "";
$('#div_table input:checked').each(function(item){
    result += $(this).val();
});
return result;
```

you're mixing up a couple of different meathods of working through an array of jQuery elements

```
      $(this).find('td').find("input:checked").each(function ()
       {
          // you already call a .each() on the inputs
           for (var i = 0; i < $(this).length; i++)
           {
              // $(this).length is always 1 since you're in a .each() loop
               str += $(this).val() + ',';
            }
        return alert(str);
      });
```

notes:

```
`.find()` will search through all layers of children
 `.each()` already iterates through each item
```